# usb write protected!

Tags: usb, write-protect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove the write protection from an USB flash disk](https://superuser.com/questions/158083/remove-the-write-protection-from-an-usb-flash-disk)

i have problem in pen drive. when i copying my data in usb then a message occur that drive is write protected.
how can i remove write protection from my usb.

Comment: Which OS are you using? Which File System is used by your pen drive?

Comment: i am using window xp OS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if there is a switch button or something on your usb that write-protect the support, just like floppy diskette, if not, try to format it

Comment: no there is nothing like switch button.

Comment: ok so try this :

http://www.troublefixers.com/remove-write-protection-on-usb-pen-drive-or-memory-card-or-ipod/