# failed to format the device

Tags: usb-flash-drive, usb-storage, write-protect

I want to format my pendrive kingston 4 GB, but i can't. I used gparted in live cd(remove partition and create new) also program HP USB Disk Storage Formatting (error: `failed to format the device`) but this isn't helping me. When i want save data on the disk i see window: `Disk write protected`. What can i do more about this problem ?

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/158083/how-to-remove-the-write-protection-from-an-usb-flash-disk (along with quite a few others)

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a small switch physically on the pendrive which is used to mark the drive read-only. While the pendrive is read-only, the drive will not allow itself to be written to in any way (formatting, or saving general data). If there is no physical switch, then there is either some software lock, or it was manufactured for a singular purpose and the read-only lock was put in at the factory (highly unlikely, but theoretically possible). If you're unsure, post the exact model and we can see if it has a write-protect switch.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Mac or a PC? PCs can use NTFS filesystems, but MACs cant. MACs have to have the filesystem formatted at FAT for it to be read properly, until it is FAT (or possibly FAT32) it will be read only.

Good Luck-

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is try a different program to format it.  Use FAT32, it is not as secure, does not have as robust back up info as NTFS, and can't hold a file larger than 4gb (not that that is a problem on a 4gb drive).  However, it will work on any operating system.  If you can't format it in a different program you should report back with the error.