# Remove Write Protection from USB

Tags: windows, windows-8, usb, usb-flash-drive, write-protect

My flash USB is write protected and I've tried every possible methods I've encountered over the internet, to get rid of this.

Accessing the usb is not working.
Format from my computer, is not working.
Clear attributes with DiskPart is not working (can't be cleaned, `Current Read-only State` is `Yes` but `Readonly` is set to `false`...

With Disk Management, I can't delete the partition...

Is there any other method... With a specific software or somehow?

**Edit** :

The USB came with no particular drivers, it's a generic one I believe, that installs and that's it.
I tried this on Windows 8.1, but it doesn't work as well on Windows 7.

These are the details extracted with `Flash Drive Information Extractor` :

[image: Flash information]

Comment: Remember to include the OS for this particular question

Comment: Which model of USB flash drive is it? Do you have any drivers from the vendor installed? Which version? Which version of Windows do you use?

Comment: Please tell us the brand/model/anything on the casing to identify it. I had a USB flash drive that went read-only no matter what you do (`clean` command in `diskpart` just hangs for ages then show error). Until I got the software from manufacturers site to format the drive, the data is always protected.

Comment: I've used the softwares in the below accepted answer to identify it, and it seems to be a Generic flash. I used Alcor MP software but it didn't recognize the flash, it said, <<Flash Unknown>>, and after browsing a little more, if it says so, there isn't anything much to do.

Comment: I have uploaded a picture with the details.

Answer (score 6):

You need to discover VID PID of yours flash drive. You can do this with help of `FlashGenius` or `CheckUdisk` etc. Here is a page with all of this utility http://flashboot.ru/files/vidpid/

Then go to http://flashboot.ru/iflash/‎ and search for special utility for your flashdrive. Simply you need to re-flash your USB flashdrive controller.

Comment: Thank for the answer, right now I'm at work but I'll look into this as soon as I'm arriving home and I'll return with what's happened. On a quick browse, I've noticed DriveGenius is for MAC

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately none of the softwares worked... My USB couldn't be identified, was <<unknown flash>> and neither programs could solve it...

Comment: @TheSAS Is there anything similar for DVDs?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Look here http://www.rpc1.org/

Comment: great.. it worked.

Comment: To the person that recommended FlashGenius at http://flashboot.ru/files/vidpid/. Trojan was quarrantined when extracted. DO NOT DOWNLOAD.