# Pen drive has a write-protected issue

Tags: usb-flash-drive, chkdsk, diskpart, write-protect

My pen drive has become write0protected. Even when I am trying to format it is giving write-protected problem. I tried many solutions I found on the internet, but all failed.

Here are my pen drive details:

```
Description: [E:]USB Mass Storage Device(Generic Flash Disk)
Device Type:  Mass Storage Device

Protocal Version: USB 2.00
Current Speed: High Speed
Max Current: 200mA

USB Device ID: VID = 058F PID = 6387
Serial Number: 5183150D

Device Vendor: Generic
Device Name: Mass Storage
Device Revision: 0102

Manufacturer: Generic
Product Model: Flash Disk
Product Revision: 8.07

Chip Vendor: Alcor Micro
Chip Part-Number: SC908(N/NL)/FC8908(N/NL)/AU6989(N/NL) - F/W F7CB
Flash ID code:  ADDE94EB - Hynix - 1CE/Single Channel [MLC] -> Total Capacity = 8GB
```

I also used the diskpart command, but nothing happened.

DISKPART results:

```
Microsoft DiskPart version 6.1.7601
Copyright (C) 1999-2008 Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: XXXXXXXX

DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     D                       DVD-ROM         0 B  No Media
  Volume 1     C   OSDisk       NTFS   Partition    298 GB  Healthy    System
  Volume 2     E   PEN Drive    NTFS   Removable   7799 MB  Healthy

DISKPART> select volume 2

Volume 2 is the selected volume.

DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          298 GB      0 B
* Disk 1    Online         7800 MB      0 B

DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     D                       DVD-ROM         0 B  No Media
  Volume 1     C   OSDisk       NTFS   Partition    298 GB  Healthy    System
* Volume 2     E   PEN Drive    NTFS   Removable   7799 MB  Healthy

DISKPART> detail disk

Generic Flash Disk USB Device
Disk ID: 6B0977BC
Type   : USB
Status : Online
Path   : 0
Target : 0
LUN ID : 0
Location Path : UNAVAILABLE
Current Read-only State : Yes
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
* Volume 2     E   PEN Drive    NTFS   Removable   7799 MB  Healthy

DISKPART>
```

Chkdsk results:
With `Automatically fix file system errors` giving write protection error otherwise
it's giving the following details:

```
E:\>chkdsk /F /X
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Cannot lock current drive.
Windows cannot run disk checking on this volume because it is write protected.

E:\>chkdsk /F
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Cannot lock current drive.
Windows cannot run disk checking on this volume because it is write protected.

E:\>chkdsk
The type of the file system is NTFS.
The volume is in use by another process. Chkdsk
might report errors when no corruption is present.
Volume label is PEN Drive .

WARNING!  F parameter not specified.
Running CHKDSK in read-only mode.

CHKDSK is verifying files (stage 1 of 3)...
  256 file records processed.
File verification completed.
  0 large file records processed.
  0 bad file records processed.
  0 EA records processed.
  0 reparse records processed.
CHKDSK is verifying indexes (stage 2 of 3)...
  278 index entries processed.
Index verification completed.
CHKDSK is scanning unindexed files for reconnect to their original directory.
  1 unindexed files scanned.
Detected orphaned file SYSTEM~1 (36), should be recovered into directory file 5.

Detected orphaned file System Volume Information (36), should be recovered into
directory file 5.
  0 unindexed files recovered.
CHKDSK is verifying security descriptors (stage 3 of 3)...
81 percent complete. (34 of 256 file SDs/SIDs processed)
Security descriptor for file 36 is missing or invalid.
Security descriptor for file 37 is missing or invalid.
Security descriptor for file 38 is missing or invalid.
Security descriptor for file 39 is missing or invalid.
  256 file SDs/SIDs processed.
Security descriptor verification completed.
  11 data files processed.
CHKDSK is examining Usn information...
The master file table's (MFT) BITMAP attribute is incorrect.
Windows found problems with the file system.
Run CHKDSK with the /F (fix) option to correct these.

   7986423 KB total disk space.
     21568 KB in 7 files.
        12 KB in 13 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
     42899 KB in use by the system.
     41984 KB occupied by the log file.
   7921944 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
   1996605 total allocation units on disk.
   1980486 allocation units available on disk.

E:\>
```

I tried doing a low level format. It destroyed my pen drive. It completed with a read-only error. Now it is asking for a format, but it gives a formatting error on the format command.
Help me to find the reason for the problem, so I can prevent this from happening to my other pen drives.
Help me to remove the write-protection.

Comment: Did you try [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Disable-Write-Protection) or [this](http://superuser.com/questions/669234/remove-write-protection-from-usb)?

Comment: I tried the Regedit and Diskpart ... Nothing happend. Clean command giving error....