# USB Storage is Write-Protected

Tags: windows-7, raid, external-hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove the write protection from a USB flash disk](https://superuser.com/questions/158083/remove-the-write-protection-from-a-usb-flash-disk)

I have a Raidon GR3630-2S-SB2+ External RAID enclosure that I've just hooked into my system. For some reason, it's coming up as write-protected.

The issue seems to have to do with my Windows setup, because I'm able to write to the drives when I plug the enclosure into another system running the same version of Windows (Windows 7 Enterprise x64).

For both of my machines I have administrative access, and "Full Control" is granted to Administrators in the Security tab of the drive properties.

Does anyone know how to enable write access to an external drive like this? Are there any other steps I could take to troubleshoot the problem? Or is there any other info that you would need?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/112401/why-would-disks-mysteriously-become-write-protected

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/148385/usb-write-protected

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/158083/how-to-remove-the-write-protection-from-an-usb-flash-disk

Comment: @Hello71, @IvoFlipse This isn't a duplicate of any of those. The drives and the storage device are functioning perfectly well and do not need to be wiped or replaced. The fix suggested by @BloodPhilia worked. Please do some research before flagging questions as duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in a .bat file and execute it:

```
cd\
reg add "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorageDevicePolicies" /t Reg_dword /v WriteProtect /f /d 0
```

Comment: this worked partially, but i need to do it for "ControlSet001" and "ControlSet002" as well. I found the problem described here: http://www.cybertechhelp.com/forums/showthread.php?t=185805

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check is to see if you can write to any removable devices on the machine as there are group policy settings which can disable write access to these devices (which I don't have off hand).

Otherwise, you can check/set the readonly status using DISKPART (Try googling for DISKPART ATTR)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - it helped me diagnose the issue but ultimately I went with @BloodPhilia's approach. I'd vote you up if I could ;)