# How to make USB drive or pen drive write protected?

Tags: security, virus, usb-storage, write-protect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write protect a USB key?](https://superuser.com/questions/269600)

I have a pen drive which I used to carry some files from my laptop to other public computers, and these public computers are virus infected. Now I want to make my pen drive write protected so that these viruses can't infect my pen drive.

What are the solutions?

Comment: Its the reverse of [this](http://superuser.com/questions/148385/usb-write-protected)

Answer (score 2):

Buy a new USB drive with a write protect switch.

Short of this, there isn't any guaranteed way.

Comment: +1 I won't add any buying recommendations but they do exist and are not hard to find - I had one and it was very handy when de-lousing infected machines.

Comment: A lot of SD cards have a write protect switch. May be less convenient, though, if the machine doesn't have a built-in cardreader.

Comment: I may be incorrect but I have read before that the implementation of the SD card slot does not demand that the write-protect switch be respected on the hardware level, so it is possible to use a device that will ignore this switch.

Comment: @Frederick - You are correct... but... I have never seen any SD card read/writer that detects this - It is down to a feature on the actual card and controller chip inside the card.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to be able to edit the registry on the system you're inserting your USB drive into.

Add (DWORD) or modify existing key at

> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorageDevicePolicies\WriteProtect`

and set to `000001` to disable writing, `000000` to enable writing.

Comment: As I have  said that these computers are public computers so I can't edit registry of these computers. Any other solution?