# Can't Format PenDrive(SanDisk Cruzer Blade)

Tags: partitioning, usb-flash-drive, formatting, write-protect

Plz read complete question before marking Duplicate.
I have a Sandisk Cruzer Blade 16GB Pendrive(No warranty left).
It have one movie file in it now, though copyable, not playable.
Problem is I can't copy to it, I can't format it. It says the pendrive is

`Copy Protected`

So, I tried

- editing registry
- Computer Management window
- Some Partition Management tools
- Windows installation CD(Partition Wizard)
- disk part
- command line format
- tried to make it into bootable system drive

So, is it dead? 
Anything else I can do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pen Drive automatically got Write-Protected](http://superuser.com/questions/391397/pen-drive-automatically-got-write-protected)

Comment: I feel I have to add my usual litany - if a USB flash/SD card etc starts playing up, try format it once. If it fails, throw it away. If it had a write error, the firmware will have triggered read-only mode, which is irreversible. Get the data off it, then throw it away.